# IFile.getFile is case sensitive

Tags: java, java-8, eclipse-plugin

Say my workspace has certain files in the root folder like foo.xml, foo1.xml, foo2.xml, foo3.xml.

```
final List<String> configFiles = new ArrayList<>();
configFiles.add("foo.xml");
configFiles.add("foo1.xml");
configFiles.add("Foo2.xml");

final List<IFile> iFiles = configFiles.stream()
                .map(project::getFile)
                .filter(IFile::exists)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When I do a getFile on the project, IFile expects a case sensitive fileName, say there is foo2.xml in my workspace and I try to access Foo2.xml, I don't get the file.
How can I get files regardless of the case ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way.

You could get call `members()` on the project:

```
IResource [] members = project.members();
```

and then match the member names using `equalsIgnoreCase`:

```
 private IFile findFile(IResource [] members, String name)
  {
    for (IResource member : members) {
      if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(member.getName())) {
        if (member instanceof IFile) {
          return (IFile)member;
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
    
    return null;
  }
```

so the stream would be:

```
   final List<IFile> iFiles = configFiles.stream()
                    .map(file -> findFile(members, file))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```